# Rerender Javascript code dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm using a web-based tool that uses Javascript to draw pretty things, like maps. I'm making an editor for it and I've implemented a way for people to write JavaScript code and then update the rendering online (I know it's risky to have any sort of JavaScript eval thing, but forgive me for the moment).

What I've been able to do:

Using jQuery, replace the old JavaScript with the new:

```
<div id="renderarea">
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Special code that actually needs to be here, not like in the head.
       Renders view with a function like render() */
</script>
</div>
```

After the magic I do, I get (seen with Firebug)

```
<div id="renderarea">
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* New code, but it doesn't run at all */
</script>
</div>
```

I tried running the "render()" function again but that didn't work either. I know there's some eval that has to take place, what am I missing?

Thanks once again!

Comment: Why does the script *have* to be in the `<div>`? That doesn't make much sense to me. If you're using jQuery, the script should be able to get the needed element using the `$` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should modify your tool so that it, rather than executing a bunch of document.writes() (which your call to "render" presumably does)....it simply produces a string of html.  If you want to call it "from within" a div on page load, fine...just document.write the string.  But if you want to call it after the page is loaded, you need to get the div (via document.getElementById() or the like), then set its innerHTML to the string.

This way it will work in both contexts.  I don't know if this is your own toolkit or what, but limiting something so that it must be executed from within the html of an element via document.write seems like it will limit its usefulness considerably.

Comment: I realized that the problem with the toolkit was that it was using JS 1.8, which doesn't quite work well, particularly with expression closures. I've since reworked the tool so that I can reference the JS externally. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Inline `<script>` injection does not execute the code.  Use `eval` for that.

If you need to `eval` inside of an iframe, use:

```
iframeDomElement.contentWindow.eval(code);
```

Comment: It's not in an iframe. How would I use `eval` to run a script that has to be located in a particular div?

Comment: why does it have to be in a div?  does it execute document.write?

Comment: If it executes `document.write`, the document will be *rewritten* if the script executes after the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this I put a link on jsfiddle

[take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/WQdMw/)

Comment: I'm not sure if that solves the issue of the script needing to be run from a particular `div`. That's the odd problem of this particular toolkit.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean by running the script from a particular div... could you elaborate?

Comment: Well the javascript needs to evaluated at the right location in the DOM (because it renders view there). It doesn't work if I just put the javascript in an external file, for example, and reference it from a script tag.

Comment: are you saying that the javascript that the user writes needs to intert elements in a specific place - the place that the div is located?

Comment: I probably still don't understand what you mean, but here is another jsfiddle that runs code from a script tag http://jsfiddle.net/R6wqy/2/